# Unable to schedule job in cloud vm

Tags: cron, python3, cloud

I have been trying to run a python script in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS vm every 15 minutes.

my cron job notation:

```
*/15 * * * * /home/userbulb1/projectfile/main.py
```

First line of my python file:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.8
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
```

also I ran the command:

```
chmod +x /home/userbulb1/projectfile/main.py
```

But the python file doesn't seem to be executing. I searched but couldn't find anything else. Why it is not working? 
I am using compute engine(google cloud)

Comment: [Redirect cron output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4811738/how-to-log-cron-jobs?rq=1) into a file so you can read the error message.

Comment: Update:  it worked if put                                                                                                  
 `*/15 * * * *  /usr/bin/python3.8  /home/userbulb1/projectfile/main.py`                                               shebang is not working apparently.